# How do I bookmark an answer on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support

How can I bookmark an answer on Stack Overflow?

I've tried searching for other questions but did not found a **specific one.**

Comment: short version: you can't, you can only bookmark questions

Comment: You can follow an answer…